# Creating associated models on create in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, associations

I have to be dead tired because I really can't figure out such simple task as this.

Having:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subscription, :dependent => :destroy

  after_save :append_subscription

  private
  def append_subscription
    # TODO
  end
end

# Subscription(id: integer, account_id: integer, level: integer (: 1), starts_at: date, ends_at:date, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

I'm trying resolve the TODO part, or am I going about it the wrong way? Here's the test.

```
describe Account do
  include AccountSpecHelper

  it "should have a subscription at least at level one on creation" do
    account = Account.create
    account.subscription.level.should be(1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why `after_save` and not `before_create` and let ActiveRecord worry about creating associated model and assigning account_id correctly?

I haven't checked, but this should work:

```
class Account
  before_create {|account| account.build_subscription(params)} # or move it to method
end
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't work, I've tried in a callback method but didn't know about the block sent to the callback. I get the following error when testing - NoMethodError in 'Account should have a subscription at level one on creation' undefined method `level' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @The Tailor can you check in script/console if it works? I created new rails application and it creates dependent subscription when creating account. And check first if it really creates subscription and saves it to DB

Comment: Yes it worked in the console and I figured out that in the test i needed to ad account.save before testing the level. Thanks!